# css3 matrix3d value applied using jQuery not taking

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, 3d, transform

I'm experimenting with rotating/animating an environment using CSS3 and javascript. So I have a cube object with faces, which lives inside a "rotator" object, which is the object that gets interacted with in the UI. I want to make it so that when you click a face, it appends it to a div outside of the rotator div, but applies the transformation matrices to the object from its parents, so that it appears with the same orientation on the outside of the "rotator" as it did inside, but can be animated and become independent of the rest of the objects in the "rotator" div.

Here is the function for the click event that should do this:

This depends on several custom functions, please see the fiddle for full code and reference to functions.

```
jQuery('#top').on('click',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).parent().is('#cube')){  // only do this if it isn't already detached
        M = jQuery(this).getTransMatrix(); // get the local transform of this
        M = M.multiply(jQuery('#rotator').getTransMatrix()); // multiply it by the rotator's transform to get the final transform
        jQuery(this).appendTo('#container'); // move this to the container div outside of the rotator
        jQuery(this).css(CSS3.prefix+'transition','none'); // make sure that style changes, etc happen instantly
        // wtf here
        console.log(M.cssTransformString()); // just to check, we see the transform string before it is assigned. It's what it should be in my tests
        jQuery(this).css(CSS3.prefix+'transform',M.cssTransformString()); // we apply the string. The wrong transformation results. If I double-check it from the console, it is NOT the string from the previous line          
    }
});
```

If you check out the fiddle, you will be able to drag around to rotate the cube. Clicking on the face will have some effect. The top face with the star is the one in question. When clicked, simply does not apply the transformation. Even if I log to console the transform string it's about to apply, the next operation does NOT result in that string being applied. It simply does not stick. HOWEVER, if I click and drag slightly, then release with the cursor still on the face, THEN the transform sticks. I have tried tracing virtually everything and I cannot figure out why the transform is only sticking if you click normally (without holding/moving at all)

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spaceboycoop/PWkB9/